# Play sound alert on any activity in Putty window

Tags: ssh, audio, terminal, putty

I've a putty connection open on my windows box and I'd like Putty to notiy me on any activity in the terminal (I'm running `tail -f` on a log file). How do I achieve that? Putty isn't necessary in that equation, I just want the sound.

Ideally, I'd like the sound to repeat until I disable it manually. This way I won't miss it, when I'm watching Simpsons in the other room.

Comment: You could run screen inside putty and turn on monitoring and audio
alerts? I don't think putty has the "smarts" to do this on its own: 
you'll need to have an application generate the ^G and then putty will beep you.

Comment: Six years later and no feature ...  Putty has the hooks: it can convert a Ctrl-G to flashing taskbar, playing sounds and whatever. It it would just do it on any activity whatsoever, it would be super useful. Time to hack PuTTY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sound-making ability which putty has is to play a sound when Ctrl-G (the ASCII BEL character) is received. You can change what it does in response to Ctrl-G from Configuration->Terminal->Bell.

After setting putty to make a bell sound, you could run "tail" like this to send a BEL character to your terminal every time "tail" prints a line:

```
tail -f /some/file | awk '{print "\07" $0}'
```

A problem with this approach is that you'll probably see buffering between "tail" and "awk". You won't see output appear line-by-line; instead it will only appear every time a couple of kilobytes of data builds up. This probably not acceptable if the intent is to be alerted every time a message is logged.

A reasonably skilled developer could write a replacement for the "tail" command which adds BEL characters to the output. For example, there's a [Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm) for tailing a file, with sample code that illustrates behavior like `tail -f`. It'd be very simple to add BEL characters to that script.